# Software to control foam rocket launcher?

Tags: 16.04

I know that in older distributions there was a package called "pyrocket" that could be used to control this little toys from Ubuntu.

Does anyone know any current package that can be installed on Ubuntu 16.04?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not on main repos anymore, but development is *(somehow)* still alive *(check out its [github repo](https://github.com/stadler/pyrocket))*.

To use it with Ubuntu, there is a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~zarquon42/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) available.

Use `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zarquon42/ppa` to add the ppa. *Xenial (16.04) its ok, but there is no Yakkety (16.10) package available at the moment*.

Then `sudo apt update && sudo apt install pyrocket` to cleanly install pyrocket.

Hope it helps.